# How to foreach and the inside is other foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I want to display user names and the skills per user. The user's display is works but skills are not working how to fix it?

**index.php**

```
<?php

$jsondata = file_get_contents("data.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$output = "";

foreach ( $json['UserData'] as $display ) {
  $output .="<p>" .$display['fname']. "</p> 

            </br>

            <h6>Skills :</h6>";

                foreach ( $json['skills'] as $value ) {

                    $output .="   <p>".$value."</p> </br>

                    ";

                }
}



echo $output;

?>
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "UserData": [

    {
        "id": "name",
        "fname": "Joey",
        "lname": "Tulang",
        "age": "29",
        "gender": "Male",
        "skills": [ "HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript" ],
        "image": [ "html.jpg", "css.jpg", "js.jpg" ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "fname": "Angelica",
        "lname": "Balce",
        "age": "20",
        "gender": "Female",
        "skills": ["C++", "Python", "PHP"],
        "image": [ "c++.jpg", "python.jpg", "php.jpg" ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "fname": "Mj",
        "lname": "King",
        "age": "21",
        "gender": "male",
        "skills": [ "Photoshop", "Figma", "Corel Draw"],
        "image": [ "photoshop.jpg", "figma.jpg", "cdraw.jpg" ]
    }       

    ]   
}
```

**and I want to display it like this.**

Joey

**Skills**

- HTML
- CSS
- JavaScript

Angelica

**Skills**

- C++
- Python
- PHP

Mj

**Skills**

- Photoshop
- Figma
- Corel Draw

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `foreach ( $display['skills'] as $value ) {` instead.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted if it was the answer to your question :)